# jquery checking all file upload by array every stop after a file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I would like to apply ajax to upload pictures and give them names:

the js part of upload picture functon is:

```
function sendFile(file) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '@routes.CommonController.uploadhandler("")' + file.name,
    data: file,
    success: function () {
        return true;
        },
    error: function(){
        return false;
        },
    xhr: function(){
        // get the native XmlHttpRequest object
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
        // set the onprogress event handler
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt){ console.log('progress', evt.loaded/evt.total*100) } ;
        // set the onload event handler
        xhr.upload.onload = function(){ console.log('DONE!') } ;
        // return the customized object
        return xhr ;
        },
    processData: false,
    contentType: file.type
    });
}
```

The filelist is FileList Object. It should be: FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2, item: function}

The management of uploading every picture function is:

```
$("#px-submit").click(function(event){
    var arrayfiles=[];
    var filelist=$("#filename").prop("files");
    for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
        arrayfiles[i] = filelist[i];
    }
    console.log("arrayfiles:", arrayfiles);
var allsuccess=arrayfiles.every(function(element, index, array) {
    console.log("sending:", element.name);
    var r=sendFile(element);
    return r;
    });
if(allsuccess){
    $("form" ).reset;
    alert("All your pictures are already uploaded!");
}else{
    $("form" ).reset;
    alert("Some error during uploading pictures, you should upload the picture again");
}
```

I change the fileList to Array and then use Array.every try to confirm everyfile is already upload. but it always stop when one of file upload. why happens like this? And how to change it to confirm the 2 or more files already uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to think about:

```
var filelist=$("#filename").prop("files");
```

What is the `filelist` variable supposed to represent and what is `$("#filename").prop("files")` returning? I would assume it's returning a string, in which case you're iterating over a string.

Your for loop looks a little strange, it does not have a terminating condition:

```
for (var i = 0; f = filelist[i]; i++) {
   arrayfiles[i]=f;
}
```

I might consider re-writing the for loop to something like the following (assuming `filelist` is an array):

```
for (var i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
   arrayfiles[i] = filelist[i];
}
```

Comment: the filelist is FileList Object. It should be: FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2, item: function}

Comment: the loop is terminated, because the if filistlist[3] (assume only two elements), it return undefined and for test is true or false. the javascript will regarded as false. it is the same as you write.